# integrating svn repositories at google code

Tags: svn, google-code

I have two projects at google code. I would like to have the first linked to the second, it means, in the second project I have a folder that points to the first project. When I run svn up at the second folder, the folder that points to the first repository must be updated too.

Comment: Have you looked at svn externals? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `svn:externals` property.  Let us assume the projects are 'project1' and 'project2'.  When you check out the trunk from project2, you want a subdirectory called project1 containing project1's trunk.  Here's what you need to do:

```
svn propset svn:externals 'project1 https://project1.googlecode.com/svn/trunk' https://project2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

`svn:externals` is a versioned property, so it will generate a commit.

You can just as easily apply the property to a working copy and commit it.  See `svn help propset`, in the `svn:externals` section.